# Adding filter to a single path in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I had a look at other similar questions and this is not a duplicate.

I want to add a Spring filter to a single path pattern. I had a look at other answers but that doesn't solve my problem.

I am using spring boot 2.0.0.M7 build.

What I want is

- For all the paths /actuator/** default spring boot actuator should apply.
- For all the paths /api/v1/** permit all. On these path the actuator should not apply.
- For all the paths /api/v2/** I want to add a custom filter to this path. NOTE: BasicAuthenticationFilter and other auth filters should not be applied to this path. For our organization we have custom authentication and I implemented that in my custom filter. On these path the actuator should not apply.
- For all the other paths it should return 404. On these path the actuator should not apply.

I tried to do this with 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter classes but it's not working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 2)
public class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic().and().formLogin()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}



@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 1)
public class MyApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * isis auth filter
     */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "isisAuthFilter")
    private Filter isisAuthFilter;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous()
            .and().antMatcher("/api/v2/**")
            .addFilterAfter(isisAuthFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone here to help me.